# LARAVEL framework and Eloquent ORM model

Tags: laravel, orm, eloquent

```
{ "_id" : 8751, "title" : "The Banquet", "author" : "Dante", "copies" : 2 }
{ "_id" : 8752, "title" : "Divine Comedy", "author" : "Dante", "copies" : 1 }
{ "_id" : 8645, "title" : "Eclogues", "author" : "Dante", "copies" : 2 }
{ "_id" : 7000, "title" : "The Odyssey", "author" : "Homer", "copies" : 10 }
{ "_id" : 7020, "title" : "Iliad", "author" : "Homer", "copies" : 10 }
```

Above is a 'books' table

Using LARAVEL framework and Eloquent ORM model, how to return the following result:

```
{ "author" : "Homer", "books" : [ "The Odyssey", "Iliad" ] }
{ "author" : "Dante", "books" : [ "The Banquet", "Divine Comedy", "Eclogues" ] }
```

I am learning Laravel.

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: It seems like you are looking for a one to many relationship? If so: https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/eloquent-relationships#one-to-many

Comment: do i need to slipt the books table?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use [GROUP_CONCAT](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/group-by-functions.html#function_group-concat).

```
Book::groupBy('author')
    ->select(DB::raw('GROUP_CONCAT(title) as books'), 'author')
    ->get()
    ->map(function ($author) {
        $author->books = preg_split('/,/', $author->books);
        return $author;
    });
```

This will get you:

```
{ "author" : "Homer", "books" : [ "The Odyssey", "Iliad" ] }
{ "author" : "Dante", "books" : [ "The Banquet", "Divine Comedy", "Eclogues" ] }
```

Comment: I need to get the exact same output

Comment: Just like I said, you just need to add a splitter then... I have updated my answer to match your output.

Answer (score 0):

If the table structure is within your control, then the better solution would be to place the data into two tables `books` and `authors`, to avoid data duplication as is the case now with a single table.

Then define two [Eloquent Models](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/eloquent#defining-models) and setup a **one-to-many** relationship. As in **one** author can have **many** books written.

So the `Book` model might look like this:

```php
class Book extends Model
{
    public function author()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(Author::class);
    }
}
```

And the `Author` model might look like this:

```php
class Author extends Model
{
    public function books()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(Book::class);
    }
}
```

Now you can use the [relationship](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/eloquent-relationships#one-to-many), [eager loading](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/eloquent-relationships#eager-loading) and a little [collection processing](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/collections#method-pluck) to fetch the data in your preferred format:

```php
$authors = Author::with('books')->get()->map(function ($author) {
    return [
        'author' => $author->name,
        'books'  => $author->books->pluck('title')
    ];
});
```

You might also want to read up on [Database Normalization](https://www.1keydata.com/database-normalization/), and in your case more specifically [The 1st Normal Form](https://www.1keydata.com/database-normalization/first-normal-form-1nf.php).